Pass 'self' into a function defined via python exec in a class method
I have the following piece of code:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "foo"
    def hello(self):
        exec("def func():\n print(self.name)")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

aa = A()
aa.hello()

Running this code triggers the pdb shell. Then I observe that
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) func
<function func at 0x750d187a6950>
(Pdb) func()
*** NameError: name 'self' is not defined

So, func is a known function. However, self is not defined.
How to fix this?
Update: To clarify, my intent is to define a function dynamically in a class method, such that the function's execution depends on properties of an instance of that class.
Update 2: To clarify, I wanted the debugger to act as a shell -- that is specific to my use case. (That's why I included pdb line in my code snippet);
The snippet here is just a simplified snippet of my use case, which involves dynamically creating a bunch of functions based on some user input. And the user can interact with those functions through a pdb session
Update 3: Thanks @Ammar. I have upvoted your answer. What about the case where the function execution depends on executing a method (not just a property)?  As an example,
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("running foo")
    def hello(self):
        exec("def func():\n self.foo()")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

aa = A()
aa.hello()


In your function func() there are no parameters passed hence it throws error NameError: name 'self' is not defined.
Try this:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "foo"
    def hello(self):
        exec(f"def func(name):\n print(name)")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

aa = A()
aa.hello()

In the ternimal, pass self.name in func()
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) func(self.name)
foo
(Pdb)

Updated answer to the edited question
from textwrap import dedent
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "foo"
    def hello(self):
        exec_code = dedent('''
        name = self.name
        def func():
            global name
            print(name)
        ''')
        exec(exec_code)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

aa = A()
aa.hello()

In the terminal:
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) func()
foo
(Pdb)  

Update 3 answer
Same procedure, store self (instance) in a global variable and use that variable to call the instance's methods.
Code:
from textwrap import dedent
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("running foo")
    def hello(self):
        exec_code = dedent('''
        curr_obj = self
        def func():
            global curr_obj
            curr_obj.foo()
        ''')
        exec(exec_code)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

aa = A()
aa.hello()

Terminal:
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) func()
running foo
(Pdb)


I didn't downvote. I will say, that if you are going to use exec like this then it is probably best to make that function take everything as an argument.

This isn't my intent. My intent is to define a function dynamically in a class, and the function's execution depends on properties of an instance of that class.

Should have mentioned that before. Your original question was merely asking for the fix to the given error. And I gave my answer accordingly. If you had mentioned your intent beforehand, I would have given my answer accordingly.

As I type this out, I realized the solution!!!!
Treat locals as globals!!
So,
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "foo"
    def hello(self):
        exec("def func():\n print(self.name)", locals())
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

So the locals of method hello which contains self becomes
the global context of func -- thus func knows what self is!
Note that the default exec behavior is exec(code, None, None)
which is the same as exec(code, globals(), locals()). But self won't make sense to func as a local variable
since it is not defined within the function.
Update. Just to note that this answer works for the updated scenario as well.

Modifying locals() is still undefined behavior. You'll run into all sorts of weird issues with inconsistent variable values or variables seeming to only sometimes exist.

And in case it wasn't clear, defining a function with def in exec this way is an attempt to modify locals().

This isn't going to work, at least, func will be undefined if you try to use it inside of hello , it may or may not exist in locals()['bar']. If you are going to do this, you should manage the namespace explicitly with some dict, or better yet, you should not use exec here to begin with

My intent is to define a dynamic function inside a class method. If you can provide a solution for it that would be great. @user2357112

I tried, it works. In the pdb shell, I can type func() and it returns foo. @juanpa.arrivillaga

@zkytony the debugger is doing some hack. Try it without a debugger

Why don't you just use a function definition statement? Why use exec at all?

I wanted the debugger to act as a shell -- that is specific to my use case. (That's why I included pdb line in my code snippet) @juanpa.arrivillaga

This is just a simplified snippet of my use case, which involves dynamically creating a bunch of functions based on some user input. And the user can interact with those functions through a pdb session @juanpa.arrivillaga

you haven't explained why this requires using exec. and why make users interact through a pdb session?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
